# Ensure item is in array and return item

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm looking for a quick way to validate an item is in an array, and return that item. So far, I have:

```
item = :foo
whitelist = [:foo, :bar]
(whitelist & [item]).first # => :foo
```

or in one line:

```
([var] & [:foo, :bar]).first
```

Is there a more ruby way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
whitelist.find{|e| e == item} # => :foo
```

or

```
whitelist.grep(item).first # => :foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are more than one *items* you want to check for:

```
candidates.find { |item| whitelist.include? item }
```

Assuming it is only one *item*:

```
item if whitelist.include? item
```

Answer (score 0):

```
whitelist.include?(item) && item
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var = :foo
whitelist = [:foo, :bar]

whitelist.include?(var) ? var : nil
```